# Eigenvalue Comparison

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ be a real matrix, if some of its diagonal entries perturbed by subtracting postive real numbers, then what can we say about the eigenvalues of perturbed matrix in comparison to eigenvalues of the original?

I know that if every diagonal entry of $A$ decreased uniformly by $k(>0)$ amount then real part of every eigenvalues of perturbed will be shifted by $k$ amount left side.

I am especially intrested in any comparison between $\max Re\lambda (A)$ and $ \max Re\lambda (A -D),~D$ is a diagonal matrix whose at least one entry is positive.

Comment: There is a notion of $\le$ for Hermitian matrices but for arbitrary matrices I don't know what you mean. And what is $\lambda$, any complex number?

Comment: @Keith McClary arbitrary means; no restriction on the matrix type. $\lambda(M)$ represents the eigenvalue of the matrix.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this is true, say by numerical simulation?

Comment: @Nao some trivial intuitions; diagonal matrices. More, I know the result is true for hermitian matrices (Keith also mentioned in the comment).  I have not simulated, but trying to confirm this result theoretically.

Comment: Subtracting $kI$ just reduces the real part of the eigenvalue by $k$, so you can move $kI$ to the LHS, if that's any help.

Comment: It helps when we compare the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A-kI$ but this is not the case here

Comment: How did you prove the result for Hermitian matrices?

Comment: @Nao by weyls inequality

Comment: I mean, you could reframe your question as "what happens to the eigenvalues of $A$ under the perturbation $(kI-D)$".

Comment: Thanks, i understood now ..it simplified some extent.

Comment: Related?: [How do eigenvalues change if we perturbe the diagonal entries of a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170241/how-do-eigenvalues-change-if-we-perturbe-the-diagonal-entries-of-a-matrix)